# Building immutable map using a list of objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of students and a delegate that has a function to get a list of servers for a given student (`getServersForStudent(student)`). I would like to create a map for a list of students indexed for each server. A student can be in many servers.

```
private Map<Server, Student> getStudentsByServer(List<Student> students) {
    Map<Server, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<>();
    students.forEach(student ->
        List<Server> servers = delegate.getServersForStudent(student);
        if (!servers.isEmpty()) {
            servers.forEach(server -> map.putIfAbsent(server, new ArrayList<>()).add(student));   
        }
    );
    return map
}
```

This works perfectly, but I would like to refactor this to use streams in order to make an immutable collection instead. I tried doing this with groupingBy, but I wasn't able to get the right result:

```
students
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            student -> delegate.getServersForStudent(student);
            Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())
        )
);
```

This grouping doesn't have the same result as above since it is grouping by lists. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to best do this with Java streams?

Answer (score 5):

Streams are not required to return an immutable collection; simply copy your collection into an immutable one in the end or wrap it in an unmodifiable wrapper:

```
private Map<Server, Student> getStudentsByServer(final List<Student> students) {
    final Map<Server, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (final Student student : students) {
        for (final Server server : delegate.getServersForStudent(student)) {
            map.computeIfAbsent(server, new ArrayList<>())
                    .add(student);
        }
    );

    // wrap:
    // return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    // or copy:
    return Map.copyOf(map);
}
```

If you really want to do it stream-based, you have to first create a stream of tuples `(student, server)`, which you can then group. Java does not have a specific tuple type, but short of creating a custom type, you can misuse `Map.Entry<K, V>` for that:

```
students
    .stream()
    .flatMap(student -> delegate.getServersForStudent(student)
            .stream()
            .map(server -> Map.entry(student, server)))
    .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    tuple -> tuple.getValue(),
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            tuple -> tuple.getKey(),
                            Collectors.toList())));
```

Note that the collection return by Collectors don't make any promises about the (im)mutability. If you require immutability, you have to add another collection step using `Collectors.collectingAndThen`:

```
    .collect(
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            tuple -> tuple.getValue(),
                            Collectors.mapping(
                                tuple -> tuple.getKey(),
                                Collectors.toList())),
                    Map::copyOf);
                    // or wrap with: Collections::unmodifiableMap
```

And it's definitely worthwhile to mention that an unmodifiable/immutable map as in the example above still allows to modify the list of servers, because that `Collectors.toList()` currently returns an `ArrayList`. If you require the value of the map to be immutable too, you have to take care of that yourself, e.g. using `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList` or by copying/wrapping the list again.

Comment: I still wanted to see how a functional approach would look for this problem. I think it might be easier to reason about using streams.

Comment: @ptt answer was updated

Comment: You can use `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()` to make the lists immutable as well.

Comment: `map.computeIfAbsent(server, k -> new ArrayList<>())` is better than `map.putIfAbsent(server, new ArrayList<>())`.

Comment: @ﾓｷｬﾃﾞ right, thanks! I didn't notice that when copying from the question